# When asp.net validate on client. is there any event will fire?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i have an asp.net page.
On this page, i have many control need to validate.
Eg. 1 textbox using to enter email address, i validate by RegularExpressionValidator control.
when lost focus on this textbox, if the text i enter is not valid. it's will show

-> so do you know which event that i can access on client to customize this

(I dont want to check each control on form (because so many control))

Comment: What is your current code? How exactly you want to customize it? Better do it properly, not "hack" into the internal JS code as it can change in future updates or versions of the .NET framework.

Comment: I'm using a RadWindow (Usercontrol from telerik). I set it autosize, that mean when the Window is popup it will make a nice size for me. the problem now is, it only calculate the size without some validate control (is hidden). So when validate fail, control appear, window size will not correct. They have a function setAutosize(true) to caculate again. so that. i need to put this function in correct place

Comment: I fear you'll have to post in their forums, better not try to "hack" into their internal coding.

Comment: I searching in their forum, and they say, no way to call a javascript function when a control is being validate. I need using a customize validate control to call js function each time it validate. Look like noway :(. anyway thank you

Comment: Yep, not going to be a walk in the park.